# PHP | Shuffling/Randomizing an array

Tags: php, arrays, random, shuffle

Lets assume that I have a lottery site in which 10 people are entered and inserted into an array. Of course it is a highly sensitive task to randomly shuffle the array of 10 people and pick one random winner.

I intend to use the `shuffle` function to randomly pick the winner out of the array. Is this a good way to do it since the lottery is of course sensitive and needs to be 100% random and not Reversible (for the candidate to try and trick).

If I am going about it the right way, what techniques/code could I add to further randomize the array and make it 100% more bullet proof. It just feels incorrect that I can run just one function and essentially be done.

Any guidance please?

Comment: You could leave the array as it is and use [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) to generate a random array key, e.g. `$lottery[mt_rand(0, count($lottery) - 1)];`

Comment: @StuartWagner I dont understand how this will aid when i come to choose the winner/choose the array.

Comment: it randomly selects an array key between the ranges of 0 and the array total length.  So say you have 5 names in your array it randomly picks a key for entries between 0 and 5 and then returns the contents of the key's value.

Comment: @Dave actually, it would return between 0 and 4.

Comment: yeah I didn't notice the -1 :) same logic applies though.... I just can't count :)

Comment: So that would obviously not work if the last guy entered physically cant win...

Comment: @Eclipse `mt_rand()` does a slightly better job of generating a random value than `shuffle()`. That's the only difference, really. If you wanted to influence the odds of the lottery, that would require some additional logic.

Comment: So if i used a combination of shuffle and mt_rand, do you think that is enough?

Comment: @Eclipse I would avoid `shuffle()` and use `mt_rand()` instead.

Comment: @eclipse no need to use both just do it as Stuart said it'll do exactly what you want and it WILL include the last guy to enter its just arrays count from zero thats why there's a -1 on  total array length count.

Comment: Also, I should note that once PHP7 comes out, you should switch to [`random_int()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php).

Comment: So I will ask again, using purely that 1 line logic is enough for something like this you think?

Comment: @Eclipse Yes, using `mt_rand()` should get you what you need. It doesn't need to be complicated, unless you want it to be ;)